# How can i "put together" the db context from code first,and the another on with db first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using identity server - code first approach.The tables are auto generated and everything is fine.But now i have a custom tables,that are little complex to build with EF,and i want to use db first approach in this situatuon,
i know that i can use code in package manager console where EF wil lbuild automatic the classes for me.But,will there be any problems in my application because of the two db context's ?

```
//here is the context from the code first approach

 public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AuthenticationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Short answer is no , there is no issues with multiple db contexts. But recommendation is changing it to code first approach. If you are not good in addign complex objects , then create it in Database and then generate the model using Create from existing database option in EF.

Comment: I must use code first approach because of the identity server...